# Validation Lumen/Laravel não funciona

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, lumen

Estou criando uma API utilizando o Lumen v5.8, e antes de salvar os dados no banco estou validando dados de um array enviado pelo usuário porém os dados nunca passam na validação.

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Lista;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ListaController extends Controller{

    public function index(){

        return response(Lista::all());
    }

    public function store(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'nome' => 'required|max:20'
        ]);// o código não passa daqui 

        $request = $request->json()->all();
        $lista = new Lista();
        $lista->nome = $request['nome'];
        try{
            $lista->save();
            return response(['201']);
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            return response(['400']);
        }
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id){

    }  
    public function delet($id){

    }

}
```

Rota

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$router->group(['prefix' => 'listas'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('/','ListaController@index');
    $router->post('/','ListaController@store');
    $router->put('/','ListaController@update');
    $router->delete('/','ListaController@delete');
});
```

Postman 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Postman, na linha onde você selecionou raw, mais a direita está marcado como texto, muda para JSON (application/json).